# activerecord method missing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, soap, savon, wash-out

here is the error when i try to send soap request, it can be syntax error of activerecord version

```
activerecord (3.1.3) lib/active_record/base.rb:1088:in `method_missing'
  app/models/subscription.rb:16:in `log_remove_subscription'
  lib/subscriptions/subscribe_command.rb:169:in `unsubscribe'
  app/controllers/application_controller.rb:138:in `service_deactivation_by_cell_no'
  app/controllers/vas_api_controller.rb:90:in `DeActivate_VAS_Request'
  actionpack (3.1.3) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
  actionpack (3.1.3) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.1.3) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.1.3) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (3.1.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:443:in `_run__4307252126358694069__process_action__2271299385613156537__callbacks'
  activesupport (3.1.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:386:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
  activesupport (3.1.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (3.1.3) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.1.3) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:17:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.1.3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (3.1.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:53:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (3.1.3) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
  activesupport (3.1.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:53:in `instrument'
  actionpack (3.1.3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.1.3) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:201:in `process_action'
  activerecord (3.1.3) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.1.3) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
  actionpack (3.1.3) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
  actionpack (3.1.3) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:193:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (3.1.3) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (3.1.3) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:236:in `block in action'
  wash_out (0.9.0) lib/wash_out/router.rb:83:in `call'
  wash_out (0.9.0) lib/wash_out/router.rb:83:in `call'
  rack-mount (0.8.3) lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:152:in `block in call'
  rack-mount (0.8.3) lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:96:in `block in recognize'
  rack-mount (0.8.3) lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:75:in `optimized_each'
  rack-mount (0.8.3) lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:95:in `recognize'
  rack-mount (0.8.3) lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:141:in `call'
  actionpack (3.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:532:in `call'
  exception_notification (2.4.0) lib/exception_notifier.rb:19:in `call'
  actionpack (3.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.3.6) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
  rack (1.3.6) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:35:in `call'
  actionpack (3.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
  actionpack (3.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (3.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:247:in `call'
  rack (1.3.6) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:195:in `context'
  rack (1.3.6) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:190:in `call'
  actionpack (3.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:331:in `call'
  activerecord (3.1.3) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
  activerecord (3.1.3) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:477:in `call'
  actionpack (3.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
  activesupport (3.1.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:392:in `_run_call_callbacks'
  activesupport (3.1.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (3.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `call'
  rack (1.3.6) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:101:in `call'
  actionpack (3.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:48:in `call'
  actionpack (3.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:47:in `call'
  railties (3.1.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:13:in `call'
  rack (1.3.6) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:24:in `call'
  rack (1.3.6) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (3.1.3) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
  rack (1.3.6) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
  actionpack (3.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:53:in `call'
  rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:136:in `forward'
  rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:143:in `pass'
  rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:155:in `invalidate'
  rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:71:in `call!'
  rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:51:in `call'
  railties (3.1.3) lib/rails/engine.rb:456:in `call'
  railties (3.1.3) lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
  passenger (3.0.13) lib/phusion_passenger/rack/request_handler.rb:96:in `process_request'
  passenger (3.0.13) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_request_handler.rb:516:in `accept_and_process_next_request'
  passenger (3.0.13) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_request_handler.rb:274:in `main_loop'
  passenger (3.0.13) lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:206:in `start_request_handler'
  passenger (3.0.13) lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:171:in `block in handle_spawn_application'
  passenger (3.0.13) lib/phusion_passenger/utils.rb:479:in `safe_fork'
  passenger (3.0.13) lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:166:in `handle_spawn_application'
  passenger (3.0.13) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:357:in `server_main_loop'
  passenger (3.0.13) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:206:in `start_synchronously'
  passenger (3.0.13) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:180:in `start'
  passenger (3.0.13) lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:129:in `start'
  passenger (3.0.13) lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:253:in `block (2 levels) in spawn_rack_application'
  passenger (3.0.13) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:132:in `lookup_or_add'
  passenger (3.0.13) lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:246:in `block in spawn_rack_application'
  passenger (3.0.13) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:82:in `block in synchronize'
  <internal:prelude>:10:in `synchronize'
  passenger (3.0.13) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:79:in `synchronize'
  passenger (3.0.13) lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:244:in `spawn_rack_application'
  passenger (3.0.13) lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:137:in `spawn_application'
  passenger (3.0.13) lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:275:in `handle_spawn_application'
  passenger (3.0.13) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:357:in `server_main_loop'
  passenger (3.0.13) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:206:in `start_synchronously'
  passenger (3.0.13) helper-scripts/passenger-spawn-server:99:in `<main>'
```

Here is the gem file

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '3.1.3'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'execjs'
gem 'therubyracer'
gem 'savon' ,"~>2.0.0"
gem 'wash_out',"~>0.9.0"
source 'http://gems.github.com'
gem 'dalli', '1.0.3'
gem 'mysql2', '>=0.3'
gem 'kgio', '2.3.3'
gem 'hpricot', '0.8.4'
gem 'daemons' #, '1.1.0'
gem 'rake', '>=0.9.2'
gem 'text', '0.2.0'
gem 'thinking-sphinx', '2.0.10', :require => 'thinking_sphinx'
gem 'ts-datetime-delta', '1.0.2', :require => 'thinking_sphinx/deltas/datetime_delta'
gem 'memcache-client', '1.8.5'
gem 'starling', '0.10.1'
gem "wice_grid", '3.0.4'
gem 'will_paginate', '3.0.pre2'
gem 'rufus-scheduler', '2.0.9'
gem 'debugger'
gem 'exception_notification', '2.4.0', :require => 'exception_notifier'
gem 'paperclip', '2.3.11'
gem 'aws-s3', '0.6.2'
gem 'ar-octopus', :git => "git://github.com/tchandy/octopus.git", :require => "octopus"
gem 'capistrano' , '2.12.0'
gem 'delayed_job_active_record'
gem 'libxml-ruby', '2.0.9'
gem 'prototype-rails'
gem 'sprockets', '2.0.4'
```

Here is log_remove_subscription method, error is occurring on line 16 of code as shown in error log message

```
def self.log_remove_subscription(member_id)
  subscritpion = Subscription.find_all_by_member_id(member_id)
  original_names= ["id", "updated_at", "created_at"]
  alias_names= ["log_id", "l_updated_at", "l_created_at"]

  unless subscritpion.blank?
    keys, values = Utility.get_key_values(subscritpion, original_names, alias_names)
    result = SubscriptionLog.import keys, values, :validate => false
    subscription_member_ids = subscritpion.collect { |subscription| subscription.member_id  } 
    conditions = ["member_id IN (?)", subscription_member_ids]
    SubscriptionRequest.log_remove_subscription_requests(subscription_member_ids,conditions)
    destroy_all(conditions) unless result.num_inserts < 1
  end
end
```

Comment: Share `app/models/subscription.rb`. Error is on line 16 in method `log_remove_subscription `

Comment: log_remove_subscription added. @KirtiThorat

Comment: it's still unclear where line 16 is.

Comment: result = SubscriptionLog.import keys, values, :validate => false